# It's pointing at the less than sign saying invalid syntax

Tags: python

```
weight = float(input("What is your weight:", ))
height = float(input("How tall in inches are you:", ))
BMI = weight * 703/height
if person_weight >= 18.5 or <= 25:
    print("You have optimal weight!")
elif person_weight < 18.5:
    print("You are underweight, start eating more!")
elif person_weight > 25:
    print("You are OVERWEIGHT do something with your life!")
```

This is what happened:

```
File "main.py", line 4
    if person_weight >= 18.5 or <= 25:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

I tried running the 18.5 and the 25 on opposite sides but that didn't work.

Comment: Yes, because that syntax is invalid. It's a binary operator with only one operand. Or _what_ less than or equal to 25?

Comment: How would I rewrite the code?

Comment: It would need to read like this instead `if 18.5 <= BMI <= 25:`

Comment: I haven't found quite the right duplicate yet, but.... `person_weight >= 18.5` is a valid expression which resolves to a boolean value.  `<= 25` is not.  It's missing the value before the operator.  You're thinking of this in terms of human intuition rather than in terms of programming logic.

Comment: Well one obvious way is to avoid the problem entirely and make that the else case.

Comment: What is `person_weight` here? I think it should be `BMI`. If you want to check if a person has a bmi between 18.5 to 25, you can write `if 18.5 <= BMI <= 25:`

Comment: I'm still confused.                                                                                                 I wrote the " if person_weight >= 18.5 or <= 25: " like this because to me it's saying:  if person_weight is greater than or equal to 18.5 or less than or equal to 25 than print(" You have optimal weight!")

Comment: `if person_weight >= 18.5 or person_weight <= 25`

Comment: @ImConfusedCanYouHelpMe: *"because to me it's saying..."* - But to the Python interpreter it's a syntax error.  Computers don't have human intuition.  They're not going to figure out what you meant.  They're going to do only and exactly what they're told.  **Very** literally.  What you have are two expressions joined by an `or` operator.  Those two expressions are separate from one another.  One of them is complete and valid, the other one is not.

Comment: How would you guys rewrite the whole entire program. Btw keep in mind I just started learning python. So if you guys could explain it as well that would be nice.

Comment: @ImConfusedCanYouHelpMe: *"How would you guys rewrite the whole entire program."* - I'm afraid your question is too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  You are encouraged to narrow down the problem to something more specific.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78082869).

Answer (score 2):

```
if person_weight >= 18.5 or <= 25:
```

This is a syntax error.

In everyday human english conversation, when you say "if x is greater than y or less than z", it is understood that you're talking about x in both comparisons.

But Python doesn't work that way.  You have to explicitly put all the variables in every comparison:

```
if person_weight >= 18.5 or person_weight <= 25:
```

But I would say that this comparison is meaningless, because it will ALWAYS be true.  Every number you can possibly think of will either be greater than or equal to 18.5, or less than or equal to 25.

Perhaps you meant this as an AND condition, not an OR condition?  Did you actually mean to check that it is BETWEEN those numbers?

Comment: Python *does*, however, provide a convenient shorthand (matching standard mathematical notation) that doesn't require you to remember which conjunction to use or repeat `person_weight`: `if 18.5 <= person_weight <= 25:`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `person_weight`. Probably, you wanted to mention `BMI` instead. `if` statement should be mentioned either `if 18.5 <= BMI <= 25:` or `if BMI >= 18.5 or BMI <= 25:`

```
weight = float(input("What is your weight:", ))
height = float(input("How tall in inches are you:", ))
BMI = weight * 703/height
if BMI >= 18.5 or BMI <= 25:
    print("You have optimal weight!")
elif BMI < 18.5:
    print("You are underweight, start eating more!")
elif BMI > 25:
    print("You are OVERWEIGHT do something with your life!")
```

Comment: That's beside the point. The parser doesn't care about whether or not `person_weight` is defined; the name just gets recorded and a `NameError` will be raised at runtime if a value is actually needed.

Comment: @chepner, The OP has used  person_weight in conditional statement. `person_weight >= 18.5 or <= 25:`

Comment: Yes, but they are asking about the *syntax error*, which gets raised before you ever actually *execute* the code (which is when `person_weight` being undefined becomes a problem.

Comment: The syntax error could be fixed by `if person_weight >= 18.5 or person_weight <= 25:`, for example. You just fixed the pending `NameError` at the same time.